# PayPal Payments Pro for Micropayments?

Tags: paypal

PayPals offerings and their names are really confusing. I've switched my PayPal Business account to accept **Micropayments** and I want to use **PayPal API to accepts cards** on my app, I'm just not sure which API to use - is it "PayPal Payments Pro"?

Yes I understand I need to be PCI compliant to use Payments Pro, and I have that part figured but I'm just wondering **where's the API for micropayments**?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PayPal Payments Pro Direct Payment Edition is what you would need to use. You can find more info here: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/paypal-payments-pro

You can always signup for micro payment pricing as long as you use PayPal as you processor but not with the PayPal Gateway products. So if you use PayPal Payments Pro Direct Payment edition, you will be using PayPal business account and you can apply for the micro-payment txn pricing.

Here is where you can apply for the micro-payment pricing: https://micropayments.paypal-labs.com/ (follow the signup tab in the center of the page).

Comment: So you're confirming that Micropayment rates will be applied to Payments Pro transactions, right? So long as PayPal is the merchant processor..??  It seems like the information I was given in the past by PayPal techs is that even if you had micropayments setup, Pro transactions would still follow the standard rate.

Comment: Also, it looks like the link you provided for signin up to micropayments is only giving the option to completely switch the account from standard to micro.  At the X Conference a couple of years ago they introduced what I think they called Business Payments, which allowed you to use a single account, and depending on the amount of the transaction it would automatically use the better rate so you didn't have to use 2 different accounts.  Is this still available?

Answer (score 2):

They've made things a little more confusing with the changes they've made to Payments Pro lately.  It used to be called Website Payments Pro and it referred to the DoDirectPayment API.  Now they dropped the "website" part and they're just calling it Payments Pro, but they've changed it to the PayFlow API instead of using DoDirectPayment.  So, the first thing you need to do is confirm which one you got approved for, and then refer to the [corresponding documentation](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#wpp).

As for Micropayments, there is no specific API for that.  That is controlled by your PayPal account itself.  If you want to use Micropayments you'll need to have PayPal enable your account for that, but there are a couple of things to keep in mind.

Primarily, you won't get micropayments rates when using Payments Pro.  You only get that rate with PayPal payments of some kind...not direct credit card.

Also, it used to be that you had to have a separate PayPal account to send micropayment transactions to.  Not long ago, they introduced the ability to use a single account for both, and it would automatically adjust the rate depending on the amount of the payment you received.  You'll need to talk to PayPal about getting that setup for you, but again, it won't work with Payments Pro transactions anyway.

If you'll be dealing with lots of low dollar payments you'll probably just want to skip Payments Pro and go with [Express Checkout](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#ec) or [Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro).

Comment: Yes, like I said I got my account switched to Micropayments only, I just want to know what API to use.

Comment: Ok, I guess I mis-read that.  Payments Pro isn't going to follow that format to my knowledge. That will only work when using PayPal payments like Payments Standard, Express Checkout, or Adaptive Payments.  It might work with Payments Advanced, but I've never looked into that directly.

Comment: I checked the pricing table: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-advanced#pricingLightbox2 and they mention about micropayments at the bottom, but still not clear which API would work for micropayments.

Comment: From the looks of that chart I may be incorrect about whether or not they honor micropayments with Payments Pro.  It looks like they definitely do for Payments Advanced.  I'd give them a call to confirm whether or not they do with Pro.

Comment: What is it that you're still trying to find out?  Just confirmation on whether or not Pro works with Micropayments?

Comment: Yes, I need authoritative reference before I signup for any of the plans.

Comment: Yes it's still supported - just make sure you sign up for PayPal Payments Pro Direct Payment Edition (https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/paypal-payments-pro).